# Width problems with navbar

Tags: html, css, width, navbar

Im new to webdesign so I started a very simple project. I tried to make a navbar with 4 buttons spread evenly. However, when i set the width to 25% fot the li, the last element of the bar doesnt fit on the page but instead goes under the other ones. I want them all to spread evenly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<!-- Nav Bar -->
<div id="#nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="red" href="#nav">Home</a>
        <li><a class="orange" href="#OverOns">Over ons</a>
        <li><a class="yellow" href="#Nieuws">Nieuws</a>
        <li><a class="green" href="#Contact">Contact</a>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- End Nav Bar -->

<!-- Slider -->
<div class="slider">
</div>
<!-- End Slider -->

<body>
</body>
</html>


@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

/* Fix padding and marg options in different browsers */
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;  
}

.red {
    background-color:#F00;
}

.orange {
    background-color:#F90;
}

.yellow {
    background-color:#FF0;
}

.green {
    background-color:#0F0;
}

.slider {

}

ul {
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    list-style-type:none;
    border:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:#FF;
}

li {
    float: left;
    width:25%;
    border-right:1px solid #000;
}

li:last-child {
    border-right:none;  
}

li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 18%;
    color:#FFF;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
}

li a:hover {
    opacity:0.5;    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually because when elements are displayed as `inline-block`, space between the elements is rendered as text. To fix this, set the font-size on the parent to 0, then reset the font-size on the child. The default font-size on most browsers is `16px`.

Also, borders will normally add to the width of an element, instead of being included in it. You have a `1px` wide border on these elements, so it is `25%` + `2px` (one for either side) wide. Use `box-sizing: border-box` to include the width of the border in the sizing of the element.

Here is a simple example.

```css
dl {
    font-size: 0;
}
dd {
    font-size: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    width: 25%;
    text-align: center;
}
a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 7.5px 20px;
    border: 1px solid #f9fd42;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dd><a href="#">Item</a></dd>
  <dd><a href="#">Item</a></dd>
  <dd><a href="#">Item</a></dd>
  <dd><a href="#">Item</a></dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, i added the font-size 0 to ul and font size 16 to li and the inline-block, but nothing changed?

Comment: I noticed that you're using float instead of inline-block, I wouldn't recommend that as it is a misuse of floats. Anyways, the second part of the text of my answer will solve that for you. Borders add to the width of an element instead of being included in the width. Use `box-sizing: border-box` to include the border in the width.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

Usually this happens when you have some sort of padding/margin/border between elements. Easiest way to solve this is to reduce your width from 25%. Make sure the combined width is under 100%. Right now that's why your elements are going below.

What you are trying to achieve would make the elements with absolutely no space between them. Use something around 96% total. That's 24% for each li.

Alternate solution:

Set this property  --> box-sizing: border-box;
and then set your width to 25%. That should solve it. What you're essentially trying to do is to make the width of the element + padding + border + margin = 25%

Do that by using a width class and refrain from using inbuilt styling.

Welcome to web programming

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i already tried setting it to 24%, but then it leaves a gap on the right side. I want it to cover the full width of the page, is this possible

Answer (score 0):

You've a 1px border in the li, so this border take the space of other elements, in other words, the size of li is 25% plus 1 px of the border.

Verify your CSS.
This is your code.

```
li {
    float: left;
    width:25%;
    border-right:1px solid #000;
}
```

Try this.

```
li {
    float: left;
    width:25%;
    border-right:0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have a border-right, meaning each li block has a total width of 25%+1px and the last one can't fit.

Since you probably want to keep that border and having the four buttons covering all the space you can do something like this:

```
li {
    float: left;
    width: calc(25% - 1px);
    border-right:1px solid #000;
}
```

that way you remove that 1px that's causing the problem. Unfortunately calc() isn't supported by some of the older browsers: [calc() caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc)

Hope this can help you out ;D